# What happens when DHCP renew on occupied ip address?

Tags: dhcp

I am experimenting on the DHCP behavior and came across this thought.
If I did not renew/rebind in time, and waited for the lease to be finished then at this moment, when I try to perform a renew, what will happen?

From what I understand, since the lease is up, it should be free to assign to another client. If the IP address I was having previously was allocated to another client, by performing a renew on it, will I still be connected to the router? Does anyone know about this?

Thank you.
Sue~

Comment: Have you [read the spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2131)? If not, read it first.

Comment: "will I still be connected to the router?" - I assume you're referring to a residential "router" (which is really a router+switch+AP+DHCP+firewall+etc rolled into 1 box). Residential routers are not representative of other kinds of "routers" and note that routers, in general, do not necessarily have their own DHCP server, and conversely: not all DHCP servers provide router/gateway information to their clients.

Comment: @Dai yes, I have read through it, and understand the logic behind lease time. However, I am trying to due with relatively short lease time, and my system is using lwip. According to the implementation it does not support low lease time, so I was experimenting it and wants to know the above answer. thanks~

Comment: "low lease time" is not a term. Please clarify _exactly_ what you're referring to. DHCP does not have any defined bounds on the maximum - or minimum - age of an address lease.

Comment: @Dai I am not very sure of your description of the router. Basically, in my router (TP-Link) it does contains DHCP server, and I can modify the settings (e.g. Start IP address, End IP address, gateway, dns and address lease time). What I am referring to as "low lease time", is when I set e.g. 5seconds to the address lease time field. From the spec, 50% of lease time is for renewal and 87.5% is for rebind. I was just wondering if I missed this duration, and perform renewal afterwards what will happen. thank you.

Comment: I cannot think of any good reason to use such a short lease time (e.g. 5 seconds). Normally you set a lease time in _days_ or even _months_ (especially for a residential/home-use scenario). Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Dai yes, i understand it is an abnormal behavior but you can consider it as a small case scenario where you never know someone plays a prank on you, and changed the settings. However, lets get back on trace. I do remember that if an address is already allocated, arp should have worked and asked if anyone is using the address right?

Comment: Yes, but that only works if the other host using that DHCP address is online and responding - if it's crashed or offline then ARP won't get a response. If its lease has expired (and there's no grace period or sticky policy) then yes, the DHCP server _may_ issue its address to some other host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

„will I still be connected to the router?“ is a strange question in the context of DHCP, as DHCP is a UDP protocol and you never make any connections. And the DHCP client is only talking to a DHCP server and has no idea of a „router“. The other part of your question is about a renew after the lease is up. If the DHCP server has not used the IP in other assignments then you will get the IP address anyhow. If the IP is no longer available, then the response will be a DHCPNAK.

Comment: thanks for the reply, its exactly as what you have mentioned.